# Qual a finalidade do atributo "asp-area" em Web ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core

Criando um projeto *Web ASP.NET Core MVC* no *Visual Studio 2017*, me deparei que no arquivo *_Layout.cshtml* todos os elementos `a` tem um atributo chamado `asp-area` mas ele não tem nenhum valor:

```
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Afinal, qual a finalidade desse atributo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente para informar que um link/rota se refere a uma área
[ASP.NET Core areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/mt763233.aspx)

Como o `ASP.NET` vai procurar uma *controller* na pasta **Controllers** na raiz do site, se você quer usar uma *controller* que está em uma área específica precisa informar usando o atributo `asp-area`.

Exemplo:

```
/
/Areas
      /Admin
             /Controllers
                          /UsuarioController.cs
/Controllers
            /LoginController.cs
```

Para fazer um link para a controller na raiz basta usar `asp-area=""`

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Index">Logar</a>
```

Para a controller que está na *Area* Admin, usar `asp-area="Admin"`

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Usuario" asp-action="Index">Listar Usuários</a>
```

No seu exemplo então, a **HomeController** não está numa **Area**, mas na pasta **Controllers** na raiz do projeto.